# Redis zinterstore between 2 zrange

Tags: redis

I have two zrange value now:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange followers:2 0 -1
1) "1"
2) "3"
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange followers:4 0 -1
1) "1"
2) "2"
```

I have 4 users, each of their user id are 1,2,3,4

The result of zrange "1", "2", "3" are the id of users, and the command line above is to find the followers of user2 and user4

I want to use zinterstore to know which user follows both user2 and user4, how can I achieve that?
zinterstore is using between 2 set, but when I try to store `zrange followers:2 0 -1` into a set, it fails

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zadd bob_folowers zrange followers:2 0 -1
(error) ERR value is not a valid float
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing a `ZADD` when you say you want to do a `ZINTERSTORE`. Based on the [documentation](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) you'd want something like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zinterstore temp 2 followers:2 followers:4
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange temp 0 -1
1) "1"
```